# Two pages per sheet using mpdf

Tags: mpdf

Can I create a PDF with two pages per sheet using MPDF? If it's possible, how?

I can create an A4

$mpdf=new mPDF();

or an A5

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A5');

but I've been reading the documentation and I've not seen the way to create an unique sheet (A4, for example) with two pages.

Answer (score 1):

When you download this PHP class, there is a folder named "examples".

Example #43 explains how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a:

```
<!--mpdf
    <pagebreak>
mpdf-->
```

to produce a next page.

Another way is to use [`AddPageByArray()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpagebyarray.html) or [`AddPage()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html).